# Postgres: GRANT usage on schema myschema to myrole; Error

Tags: postgresql, sql-grant

I'm new to Postgres (worked with Oracle the last 23 years).
I would like to grant the usage on schema to role. But that seems to be impossible:

```
ps >create role marco_role;
CREATE ROLE
ps >create schema myschema;
CREATE SCHEMA
ps >grant usage on myschema to marco_role;
FEHLER:  Relation »myschema« existiert nicht (English: Relation does not exists)
```

What is my problem?

Answer (score 2):

To grant privileges on a schema you need to use `ON SCHEMA` [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html)

```
grant usage ON SCHEMA myschema to marco_role;
```

You probably also want to define [default privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) for new tables (that are not yet created) as well:

```
alter default privileges  
   in schema myschema
   grant select on tables to marco_role;
```

Comment: Thanks, my mistake !